# Django and live server, on rewrite, the old sources files are still used

Tags: django, caching, wsgi

I'm using Django 1.3 on an Apache server and mod_wsgi(daemon mode), with Nginx for serving static file. The database is on a separate server. The wsgi daemon runs on 2 threads with a maximum requests of 100.

I get in trouble when I override old .py files ... Not .pyc ... I'm also overriding the .wsgi config file (http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ReloadingSourceCode). Sometimes, some server requests uses the old code, and therefore an error is generated (HTTP ERROR 500). Is there a server side cache that needs be emptied?

Can this be generated by the .pyc files? Do I need to restart the Apache server or the wsgi daemon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup up ownership/permissions so that the user that code runs as under Apache cannot change code files nor create .pyc files. The user application runs as should only have ability to write to data or upload directories that it really needs to as is safer anyway.

The most reliable deployment method would be to install new version into a completely new directory hierarchy, with WSGI script file outside that tree. Then replace WSGI script file with new one referring to new directory. The WSGI script file in doing this should not be edited in place however, but a new file moved into place so filesystem does an atomic replace of the whole file and no risk of on the fly edit being picked up.

Answer (score 3):

If you remove the .pyc files and touch your wsgi files it should reload the wsgi daemon when it gets a chance, and you should be good.

On occasion I have had to restart apache in order to get my changes take affect.

Comment: I have failed to use the "touch file.wsgi" method. Instead I use apache reload which does not cause downtime.

Comment: Touch file.wsgi doesn't cause downtime, did you try it and it didn't work?

Comment: Oh eh sorry, I was referring to the downtime caused by restarting apache :)

Comment: Oh yeah, that makes sense. Good idea, anything to reduce downtime.

Comment: benjaoming. Touching WSGI script file to restart WSGI application process only works if using daemon mode. Are you sure you aren't using embedded mode without knowing it? The documentation on source code reloading explains how to check.